# Como puedo colocar objetos top y bottom en android?

Tags: java, android

Hola quiero poner un fragment debajo de un objeto y el marginBottom que lo haga hasta otro botón pero si pongo el código del layout_marginBottom se cierra la app

...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

el frameLayout esta dentro de un relative

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#F8F8F8"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:background="#F8F8F8"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/settings" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/stop"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/play"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="201dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="106dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/onair"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
        android:text="ONAIR"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedorFragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="660dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/settings"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@+id/onair"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

y el error que sale es este:

> 2019-09-16 13:42:25.358 12603-12603/com.radio.shalommadrid
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.radio.shalommadrid, PID: 12603
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.radio.shalommadrid/com.radio.shalommadrid.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: Can't
>   convert value at index 6 to dimension: type=0x12

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade el código del XML completo y el error que te da por consola

Comment: es mucho codigo y no se como ponerlo, me pide que describa mas el codigo

Comment: Es complicado saber el error si no se puede ver el contexto aunque sea mucho código es un copy paste no creo que sea mucho trabajo. Con el ejemplo que has puesto no puedo adivinar que error tienes.

Comment: adjunto una foto de lo que quiero asi entenderas mejor lo que quiero

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yo para este caso utilizaría un ConstraintLayout te dejo link a la documentación oficial para que veas como se usa.

Este te permite "anclar" el layout a otros elementos y forzarlo a que ocupe el espacio que le indiques.

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: muchas gracias, convertiendo el relative en ConstrainLayout si me deja anclar y posicionar un elemento donde quieras.

Comment: Revisar [answer]

Answer (score 1):

El error que indicas en tu pregunta:

> InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: Can't convert value at
>   index 6 to dimension: type=0x12

se debe a que estas definiendo un valor incorrecto en la propiedad `android:layout_marginBottom`,

```
...
<FrameLayout
    ...
    ...
    android:layout_marginBottom="@+id/onair"/>
...
```

**en  `android:layout_marginBottom`  debes definir una unidad de medida y no un id de otra vista**

```
...
<FrameLayout
    ...
    ...
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
...
```

---

¿Como puedo colocar objetos top y bottom en android?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si estas usando un `RelativeLayout`, para colocar el contenedor de Fragments en la parte de abajo (`bottom`) puedes usar :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Ejemplo:

```
 ...
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedorFragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="660dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/settings"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Para colocar el contenedor de Fragments en la parte de arriba (top) puedes usar :

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

ejemplo:

```
 ...
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedorFragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="660dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/settings"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo así, he añadido el botón que imagino que te has olvidado añadir

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#F8F8F8"
    android:contentDescription="TODO" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:background="#F8F8F8" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:contentDescription="TODO" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:contentDescription="TODO" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="201dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="106dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/onair"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
    android:text="ONAIR"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contenedorFragments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="660dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/settings" >


</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:text="Boton que te falta"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contenedorFragments"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Te esta dando el pete porque no puedes añadir un objeto cuando estas definiendo los margenes android:layout_marginBottom.